# Problem with greek url characters in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, url, utf-8

I'm using the following script in my website in order to create pagination "next-previous" functionality. It's a actually a Dreamweaver's code. The script uses the url to get some values and then it re-creates it. The result url in IE7 and IE8 contains non-readable  characters and at the end the page does not work properly.

```
    $queryString_met = "";
    if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
      $newParams = array();
      foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (stristr($param, "pageNum_met") == false && 
            stristr($param, "totalRows_met") == false) {
          array_push($newParams, $param);
        }
      }
      if (count($newParams) != 0) {
        $queryString_met = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
      }
    }
    $queryString_met = sprintf("&totalRows_met=%d%s", $totalRows_met, $queryString_met);

........

<a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_met=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_met - 1), $queryString_met); ?>"> << </a>
```

I don't understand which part of the code is responsible for this issue. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));

`htmlentities` encodes all non-ASCII bytes in your string, usually needlessly, and, if you don't specify a `charset` argument, guessing your strings are in ISO-8859-1, which for Greek they definitely won't be. (Hopefully, you're using UTF-8 for everything in your site.)

Use `htmlspecialchars` instead, which will leave the non-ASCII characters alone and only encode what really does have to be encoded.

However, for this to be an issue at all, you would have to be using non-ASCII characters directly in your URL. This is really unreliable; don't. Unencoded non-ASCII characters are not valid in a URI at all; they must be `%`-encoded (eg. using `urlencode`). IRIs allow non-ASCII characters, which browsers can automatically UTF-8-encode and %-encode to turn them into URIs, but IE doesn't (always) do that.

[Also the script to process query string will fail for any value *containing* the targeted names, not just those beginning with them.]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to choose document encoding for that page in dreamweaver:

Go to `Modify->Page Properties` menu and on the dialog select `Title/Encoding` and choose **Western European** encoding there.

**Edit:**

**[Also try to encode your urls.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)**

Comment: @Sarfraz thank you for your answer. My page contains greek characters too and my database is using utf-8 encoding, so turning page's encoding to Western European, causes a lot of other problems. Is this the only way to fix this issue?

Comment: @ktsixit: no this is not the only solution, try to encode your urls, see my updated answer plz.

Comment: I tried the following but unfortunately it's not working properly:

<a id="previous_type" href="#">&nbsp;<<&nbsp;</a>
                        
<?php $aaa = sprintf("%s?pageNum_met=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_met - 1), $queryString_met); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var whatever = "<?= $aaa ?>";
var whatever1 = encodeURI(whatever);
document.getElementById('previous_type').href = whatever1;
</script> 

Any suggestions?

Comment: the comment editor is not very friendly to code, I hope you understand the code I posted

Comment: I also tried using the urlencode() php function without success:

<?php 
$aaa = sprintf("%s?pageNum_met=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_met - 1), $queryString_met);;

$bbb = urlencode($aaa); 
?>

<a href="<?php echo $bbb; ?>">&nbsp;<<&nbsp;</a>

Comment: @ktsiit: try using htmlentities function